Pass terraform variables via jenkins pipeline
I am working on provisioning Azure resources (Eg. ResourceGroup) using Terraform via JenkinsPipelines.  I have a folder structure of -
az-tf-modules
 azure-rg-module
 main.tf
 variables.tf

azure-rg
main.tf
variables.tf
providers.tf


module configuration
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "entrg" {
  for_each            = var.rg_map
  name                = each.value.resource_group_name
  location            = each.value.resource_group_location
  tags                = each.value.tags
}

variable "rg_map" {
  type = map(object({
  resource_group_name = string
  resource_group_location = string
  tags = map(string)
})) 

}
I am passing the variables from the jenkins pipeline.  I am able to create first RG without any issues but when I am trying to create the second RG, terraform plan shows 1 to create and 1 to destroy.  Terraform is deleting the already existing ResourceGroup and creating the new one this is because terraform saves the resource as azureresource.name. As a temporary solution I could mitigate this by creating statefile for each resource.  However, I assume that is not a recommended solution.  Can someone suggest here how to make the terraform module as reusable while passing the resource variables from the jenkins pipeline "Build with Parameters" !!

The way you want to do this with Jenkins cannot work as the Terraform state file must contain ALL resources that define the 'desired state'.
Taking just the Resource Groups as an example, if you run Terraform with only resource group "A" first, Terraform will create a plan to get into the state of having resource group "A". So far so good.
Now you do another run and feed Terraform with only resource group "B". Terraform will create a plan to get into the state of having resource group "B". Since you already had resource group "A" in your current state, terraform will add to the plan to remove "A" as it is not in the desired state anymore.
So if you want both resource group "A" and "B", you should include them BOTH so Terraform will plan to make the necessary changes to end up with both "A" and "B".
You can theoretically indeed use different state files for each individual resource, but that is indeed bad practice.
The best way to do this is to have a tfvars file containing ALL of the resource groups you want to end up with, i.e.:
rg_map = {
  "A" = {
    resource_group_name     = "example-rg-1"
    resource_group_location = "East US"
    tags = {
      environment = "dev"
      owner       = "team-a"
    }
  }
  "B" = {
    resource_group_name     = "example-rg-2"
    resource_group_location = "West Europe"
    tags = {
      environment = "prod"
      owner       = "team-b"
    }
  }
}

and then keep adding to this same tfars file and have Jenkins run i.e.
terraform plan --var-file=your.tfvars.
You can have all your resources in 1 tfvars file, or split them into multiple and pass them all to terraform plan --var-file=file1.tfvars --var-file=file2.tfvars ..etc or keep all in 1 file as long as all resources you want are passed to Terraform. You can of course also use multiple state files i.e. per functional area, but 1 per resource is not a good idea.
If you're not doing so yet, you definitely also want to look into storing your state file in a Cloud bucket and secure it/make backups instead of keeping it local/in Jenkins (i.e. see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/securing-terraform-state-in-azure/ba-p/3787254). It can become quite a nightmare if you lose the state file and have to import all of your resources into a new state file again.
